# Google maps for Android, how to test with users?

Tags: android, google-maps, testing

I'm working on a team trying to make an Android app that uses Google maps. We each registered for our own maps api key (debug, version 1). Pretty much any time an individual is working in Eclipse, we have to repaste in our api key to the xml file or we only get the gray grid.

We have been dealing with this but we need to be able to test it with a user who wouldn't have a map api.

What is the solution to this? I did search but I don't see a solution that I can understand. I'm new to Android so please explain fully. <del>speak to me like I'm retarded</del>

If you answer by pointing to a page and there are 4-6 different "solutions" on it, I don't know which you are referring to. The answers I've seen posted are all for web pages not ANDROID. I don't have a CSS file to edit in Android. Or they are talking about sharing keys with developers, not USERS. The user does not have the ability to alter a file! Also as I mentioned we are using version 1 so cannot use "solutions" for version 2 or 3. We can't switch versions for reasons unrelated to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just send this other person an APK instead of the source code? Basiclly act as though you are releasing the app on the Google Play store. Generate a release key, sign the app with that key, and send that person an APK. They can then load the APK on to their phone or, if the have the Android SDK installed, onto the emulator that comes with it. In either case they will need to have the required components installed on their device - e.g. Google Play Services, Maps, etc - just as anyone downloading the app would. But this gets around the copy paste key issue.

Comment: More on building the APK [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html)

Comment: The user we need to test on needs to see the app working on an emulator as a user who has just downloaded the app would use it. In other words we shouldn't have to give her any special code to run it. I guess that can't be done with the debug key we have.

Comment: Right - thats why what I'm saying is just build a release apk. User can then install it on the emulator and it should run fine.